# Data is not rendered when changing pages with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using the `Link` component from `React-Router` to change pages, on the `Play.tsx` I have data that I am getting using `useEffect` from `Firestore` and that data is rendered on page using `map` function if the array length is more than 1. It works fine until I change the page and go back to `/play` where Play.tsx is rendered and there is no data at all, the data from firestore is ok but nothing is rendered on the page.

If I am using a normal `a` tag instead of `Link` will work fine.

**Play.tsx**

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<any>([]);

// code...

useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("users").orderBy("points", "desc").limit(10).get().then((data: any) => {
     data.forEach((usr: any) => {
         users.push(usr.data());
         console.log(users)
     })
   }).catch((err) => {
         console.log("An error has occured: ", err.message)
   })
}, [])

return (
   <>
{

  users.length >= 1 ?
     users.map((d: any) => {
       return (
          <div className="userWrapper" key={Math.random() * 9999999999999999999}>
             <Link to={`/user/${d.username}`}><img className="lbImage" src={d.profileImage} /></Link>
             <Link to={`/user/${d.username}`}>
                 <p className="lbUser">{d.username} {d.pro ? <img src={Pro} className="lbPro" /> : null} 
                 </p>
              </Link>
              <p className="lbPoints">{d.points} Points, {d.rank} ({d.races} Tests)</p>
          </div>
       )
     })

     : <div className="lbSpinner"></div>

}
   </>
)
```

**OtherComponent.tsx**

```
  <Link to="/play"><li>Home</li></Link>
```

**My route: Play.tsx (data rendered) -> OtherComponent.tsx -> Play.tsx (Data is not rendered)**

Note: The problem is not at the data itself because I can console.log it, the problem is at the DOM, is like the map function on `users` is not calling.

Note2: I have a condition there, if I have more than 1 user on the array it will map, if not it will show a spinner, but none of these is rendered when I come back to `Play.tsx`, and no error is consoled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your useEffect hook you are mutating the state directly by doing `users.push(usr.data())`

Should be using the setUsers function from the useState hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("users").orderBy("points", "desc").limit(10).get().then((data: any) => {
     data.forEach((usr: any) => {
         setUsers((prevState)=> ([...prevState, usr.data()]));
         console.log(users)
     })
   }).catch((err) => {
         console.log("An error has occured: ", err.message)
   })
}, [])
```

Try changing that and see if the state is working properly

Comment: Oh, thanks man, I didn't think that using push will cause that bug, also if you can make an edit and change to `setUsers((prevState) => ([..prevState, usr.data()]))`, just in case if someone has the same problem.